# Android 2.2 + SQLite + Defining referential integrity constraints

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android 2.2+ app with SQLite db support. I'm trying to define referential integrity constraints while creating the tables. I've also enabled the foreign key support by executing `db.execSQL( "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;" );` in `onCreate` and `onOpen` methods of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Afteer setting up my tables and proper foreign key references, it still allows me to `insert` rows in tables where reference records are missing. For e.g. I've following structure

```
CREATE TABLE Questions(_id integer primary key,question text not null);
CREATE TABLE Ques_Ans(_id integer primary key autoincrement,qid integer not null,
                      aid integer not null,is_correct integer default 0, 
                      FOREIGN KEY (qid) REFERENCES Questions(_id));
```

and following my data in the table

```
INSERT INTO Questions VALUES(1, 'Some text');
INSERT INTO Ques_Ans(qid, aid, is_correct) VALUES(20, 1, 0);
```

If foreign key is properly set on Ques_Ans table, 2nd insert should have failed as there is no record in `Questions` table with id `20`, but somehow my app does not thrown any error and inserts the 2nd insert statement. Can anybody tell me whats wrong over here or am I missing any configuration over here?

Update [03-Mar-2012]: After discussion thread with @Catcall

- Using `sqlite3` tool, switching on `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` foreign key works as expected
- Same thing if used via app on Emulator or on Phone does not work
- Insert statements executed using `insert()` or `execSQL()`. None of them throw `foreign key constraint failed` error
- `PRAGMA integrity_check` returns `ok`. So database is not corrupt.

Comment: +1 just for including all the SQL we might need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: just a note to future readers Same thing exist as of 2015 also

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key is on the column "qid", not on the column "_id".

This INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO Ques_Ans VALUES(20, 1, 0);
```

*should* have thrown the error

```
Error: table Ques_Ans has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

This INSERT should succeed.

```
INSERT INTO Ques_Ans VALUES(20, 1, 0, 0);
```

This one should fail.

```
INSERT INTO Ques_Ans VALUES(21, 2, 0, 0);
Error: foreign key constraint failed
```

---

Later . . .

Since it works in sqlite, but not in your emulator, the problem is probably in either the emulator or your code.

This is the idiom for database transactions.

```
 db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

Android docs suggest using [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead of [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29). Make sure you're trapping, catching, or checking for errors in every function that can return an error. So, for example, if you switch to insert(), check its return value for -1.

If that doesn't help, you might try tagging this question with "Java" (for example), or asking a new question that focuses on your code and on catching errors.

Comment: Thanks @Catcall. Originally I typed incorrect Insert query. I've corrected it by editing the original question.

Comment: Just to be clear, problem of referential integrity still exists. Change in query was just for the post, my actual code has insert script as I corrected in the question. So would appreciate any help in this matter

Comment: @Jay: Your edited query fails here with "Error: foreign key constraint failed." Try running `PRAGMA integrity_check;` to see whether your database is corrupt.

Comment: I get this behavior when I issue `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` using `sqlite3` tool, but when I try to execute the same from my App by running it on my emulator, it simply keeps on inserting. Below is my sample code in my app to insert  

    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");  
    db.beginTransaction();  
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Ques_Ans (qid, aid, i_correct) values(20,1,0);");  
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();  
    db.endTransaction();

Comment: and yes `PRAGMA integrity_check;` returns `OK`

Comment: @Jay: Sounds like your code or the emulator. See my update above.

Comment: well I've it exactly as you mentioned with `try...catch` block, its just that while putting as comment, it was getting difficult to format, so just put those statements to show the sequence of it. Regarding using `insert()` instead of `execSQL()`, I'll have a look today evening and see how it goes. I will be surprise if it work (throws error), but let me test it first. Update you soon. Regarding the emulator, I doubt as its standard emulator with Android 2.2. Also tested the same on my HTC Desire running Oxygen ROM 2.3 and also on emulator with Google API 8.

Comment: Hey @Catcall as I expected `insert` also didn't threw the error. I'm so stuck with annoying behavior

Comment: Found the problem and work around (but not the exact solution). What I was doing was calling insert statements from the `onUpgrade` method `SQLiteOpenHelper`. For some reasons, setting `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` does not work. If I call the same insert statements once I've the instance of my database helper (subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelerp`), invoke the `getWritableDatabase()` and then if I insert, it fails whenever there is foreign key violation.

Still not sure why `PRAGMA` statement does not work in `onUpgrade` method. :(

Answer (score 0):

**IN SQLite Foreign key constraints are disabled by default** (for backwards compatibility). You have to enable it explicitly using

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1
after you establishing your connection with the database. Here's the link to the official docs that explains it in more depth. http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html Please navigate to enabling foreign key support in the above link.